# How to get the selected date from a dateppicker in various devices?

Tags: android, datepicker

I am showing my time picker as follows ,

```
DatePickerDialog dateChange = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), DateSetListener, Year, Month,Day);
    dateChange.show();
```

I getting this value by the following code,

```
private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener DateSetListener =
        new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() 
        {

            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, 
                                  int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) 
            {
                Year = year;
                Month = monthOfYear+1;
                Day = dayOfMonth;
                date = Day+"-"+ Month +"-"+Year;
            }
        };
```

By this I get date on emulator ,

but in a device(Sony Xperia C , Jellybean) I can't get the selected date and the datepicker shows set button and cancel button, but in my emulator datepicker has only done option.

my question is thet is there any other way to get the selected date , why it happens?

I am doing this in a fragment.

thanks in advance

Comment: check the API version you are running in emulator and devices.

Comment: My api version is 18 , in that device it may be lesser but not too much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this,

```
public class DateAndTimePickerActivity extends Activity implements
    OnClickListener {

Button dateBtn, timeBtn;
static final int DATE = 0;
static final int TIME = 1;
int year, month, day, hour, minute,am_pm;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_date_and_time_picker);

    dateBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.date);
    timeBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.time);
    dateBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    timeBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR);
    minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    am_pm=calendar.get(Calendar.AM_PM);

}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.time:
        showDialog(TIME);
        break;
    case R.id.date:
        showDialog(DATE);
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

}

DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dateListener = new OnDateSetListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int Currentyear,
            int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

        year = Currentyear;
        month = monthOfYear;
        day = dayOfMonth;
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Date:" + day + "/" + month + "/" + year, 1).show();
    }
};

TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener timeListener = new OnTimeSetListener() {

    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minuteOfDay) {
        hour = hourOfDay;
        minute = minuteOfDay;
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Time::" + hour + ":" + minute, 1).show();
    }
};

@Override
@Deprecated
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {

    switch (id) {
    case DATE:

        return new DatePickerDialog(this, dateListener,
                year, month, day);

    case TIME:
        return new TimePickerDialog(this, timeListener,
                hour, minute, false);

    }
    return null;
}
}


definitaly it will work...
```

Answer (score 0):

use DateDialogFragment like this :

```
       FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction(); //get the fragment
     DateDialogFragment   frag = DateDialogFragment.newInstance(this, new DateDialogFragmentListener(){
            public void updateChangedDate(int year, int month, int day){
            displayDate = padding_str(day)+"-"+padding_str(month+1)+"-"+padding_str(year);
            sendDate = padding_str(year)+"-"+padding_str(month+1)+"-"+padding_str(day);
            }
            }, now);
            frag.show(ft, "DateDialogFragment");


private static String padding_str(int c) {
        if (c >= 10)
           return String.valueOf(c);
        else
           return "0" + String.valueOf(c);
    }
```